# How can I expose a service bus with a wcf service to be consumed by a silverlight client

Tags: wcf, silverlight, servicebus

In a Silverlight application, instead of consuming and writing (wcf) wrappers around messages that finally get sent to the bus, I want to send use my message bus as directly as possible.

My idea was to expose the service bus directly as a wcf service, or, in other terms, I want to bidirectionally pub/sub over the wire.

Has this been done already? Is bi-directionality doable at all? 
After all, we are (are we restricted to that?) in the http domain?

Lots of questions. Some head start would be greatly appreciated!

I am in .NET land, with using Rhino Service Bus, but the pattern should apply to different platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [Kaazing Websocket Gateway](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/)
- [Nirvana Web-based Messaging](http://www.my-channels.com/products/nirvana/web/)

Comment: you know of anything open source for any chance?

Comment: Kaazing has an open-source license: http://www.kaazing.org/confluence/display/KAAZING/License

Comment: Correct, the Kaazing WebSocket Gateway _Community Edition_ is [available under a Apache 2.0 license](https://kaazing.com/products/websocket-gateway/editions/)